# Show names from dynamically created text boxes in action page using session

Tags: php, session

`book_detail.php`

```
<td><?php
if(isset($_SESSION['chksbmt'])){
    $counts = count($_SESSION['seat']);
     for($i=1;$i<=$counts;$i++){
    echo "<input type='text' name='passenger_name' style='border:1px solid #000;' required /><br/><br/>";
        }
} ?></td>
```

`view.php`

```
<?php session_start(); 
error_reporting(-1);
if (!isset($_SESSION)){
}
    $passenger_name=$_REQUEST['passenger_name'];
   $_SESSION['passenger_name']=$passenger_name;
?>

<td><?php echo $_SESSION['passenger_name'];?></td>
```

In my `book_detail.php` page, I've used this count method to count the check boxes checked in the previous page & display that many no of text boxes in `book_detail.php`, so when there is 2 or more text boxes appeared, only the last name of the text field is showing in `view.php` page but i want to show all the names entered through the text fields.. I dont want to use database for it.. I've tried by giving header location method but its showing me undefined error syntax .. Here from `book_detail.php` i ve given action to `view.php` page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send data as array from form if you want to show all entries.

To do that, declare it in form by adding `[]` to input name. Then, you'll receive values from all input fields and you'll be able to loop through them.

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\eci_buswebsite\view_ticket.php on line 375
Array .. getting this error

Comment: i added [] this to my input name after that it's giving me the error

Comment: @Pooja7 So you have to also loop through this array, like I said before. You can't just print it.

Comment: @Pooja7 No, I can't, you have to do it. Search for `php array loop` in google.